# Select por horário de programação

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, select

Boa tarde, Pessoal!

Estou construindo uma aplicação de grade horária televisiva. Existe uma tabela no banco de dados que contem informações de (Nome do programa, descrição e horário). Na minha aplicação, o sistema ordena essa tabela de programação com base no horário atual de Brasília, e exibe o programa que está passando ao vivo, e a programação que irá passar a seguir.

O Problema é que no meu select atualmente é esse:

```
"SELECT *, TIME(horario) as horario FROM Programacao where horario >= '$gh_data' order by horario"
```

Onde a variável $gh_data é a hora atual do sistema e "horario" é o horário do programa na tabela "programação" do banco de dados.

Exemplo do problema acontecendo:

Um programa A começa as 14:00 e o programa B começa as 15:00. Quando o horário do sistema é 14:01 ele mostra que o programa atual é o B, invés do A.

Como solucionar esse problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que fazendo uma subquery para pegar a primeira programação menor que o horário atual possa resolver.

Por exemplo, a primeira programação menor ou igual a 14:01 é a de 14:00, correto? Então o select abaixo irá retornar a programação das `14:00`:

```
SELECT horario AS a
FROM Programacao
WHERE horario <= '$gh_data'
ORDER BY horario DESC LIMIT 1
```

Agora, colocando isso numa subquery você conseguirá condicionar o `WHERE` para retornar os registros cujos horários sejam maiores ou iguais ao horário do select acima, ou seja, o das `14:00`:

```
SELECT *, TIME(horario) as horario
FROM Programacao,
(
   SELECT horario AS a
   FROM Programacao
   WHERE horario <= '$gh_data'
   ORDER BY horario DESC LIMIT 1
) AS b
WHERE horario >= a ORDER BY horario
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda! Funcionou!!!